# Unity3D: Gainig two or more achievement problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created my own achievement system using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XuzwxkZ2Wk), but I'm having an issue with if the user gain two or more achievements, for example, one of my achievement is killing 10 enemies, where as another one of my achievement is picking up 30 coins. However, I made sure that the achievement is only given when it's a game-over to avoid problems, by doing so I realised that if the user achieves two ore more achievements, my all of the achievement panels will activate at the same time, meaning only one panel will be visible to the user. Is there a way to make each achievement panel appear after the other if two or more achievements is achieved.

This is my achievement script:

```
public class AchievementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
private int Defeats_10;
public int Gain30Treasure;
public GameObject AchievePanel, AchievePanel2;
public Text achieveTitle, achieveTitle2;
public Text achieveText, achieveText2;
public Animator anim, anim2;


void Update()
{
Defeats_10 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("10Enemies");
Gain30Treasure = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("treasure");

if (GameController.killAmount >= 10 && Defeats_10 != 10) //50
{
    StartCoroutine(Achieved50Kills());
}
if (GameController.Coin >= 30 && Gain500Treasure != 30)
{
StartCoroutine(Achieved30Coins());
}
}

IEnumerator Achieved50Kills()
{
AchievePanel.SetActive(true);
Defeats_10 = 10;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("10Enemies", Defeats_10);
achieveTitle.text = "10 Enemies Defeated";
achieveText.text = "You defeated 10 Enemies in a single game";
anim.SetBool("slideUp", true);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
anim.SetBool("slideDown", true);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
AchievePanel.SetActive(false);
anim.SetBool("slideUp", false);
anim.SetBool("slideDown", false);     
}


IEnumerator Achieved30Coins ()
{
AchievePanel2.SetActive(true);
Gain30Treasure = 30;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("treasure", Gain30Treasure);
achieveTitle2.text = "30 coins";
achieveText2.text = "You gained 30 coins in a single game";
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
anim2.SetBool("slideUp", true);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
anim2.SetBool("slideDown", true);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
AchievePanel2.SetActive(false);
anim2.SetBool("slideUp", false);
anim2.SetBool("slideDown", false); 
}
```

Thank you in advance! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your panels have the same height, set a counter for shown panels and multiply it in new panel's height.
for example:

```
int visiblePanels = 0;
IEnumerator Achieved50Kills() {
     AchievePanel.SetActive(true);
     var AchievePanelPos = AchievePanel.transform.position;
     AchievePanelPos.y = (90 * visiblePanels) + 10; //90 is for example Panel's height and 10 is a sample offset value
     AchievePanel.transform.position = AchievePanelPos;
     visiblePanels ++;
     Defeats_10 = 10;
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("10Enemies", Defeats_10);
     achieveTitle.text = "10 Enemies Defeated";
     achieveText.text = "You defeated 10 Enemies in a single game";
     anim.SetBool("slideUp", true);
     yield
     return new WaitForSeconds(3);
     anim.SetBool("slideDown", true);
     yield
     return new WaitForSeconds(1);
     AchievePanel.SetActive(false);
     anim.SetBool("slideUp", false);
     anim.SetBool("slideDown", false);
     visiblePanels --;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, however, I'm stilling getting the same results. I've even tried changing the 90 value to the height of my panel and changing the sample offset. Any ideas? Once again, thank you for replying!